# phpmyadmin information in pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo

Why when I write this code I don't receive the information in my database? I think the problem is in the PHP part and please explain because I want to learn.

```
<html>
  <head></head>

<body>
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=MYDBMANEHERE;host=MYDBHOSTHERE';

$user = 'u486645433_root';

$password = 'password';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['question'],$_POST['sujet'])){

$username = $_POST['sujet'];
$password = $_POST['question'];
$stmt = $dbh->exec('INSERT INTO `u486645433_membr`.`posta` (`sujet`,    `question`, `id`) VALUES ('.$username.', '.$password.', NULL);');
}

?>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 15%; background-color: rgb(106, 218, 111); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;" class="jumbotron">

<input placeholder="search" style="position: absolute; width: 20%; height: 62%; top: 20%; font-size: 27px; font-family: ar essence; left: 25%;" type="text">
<input value="home" name="lien1" onclick="self.location.href='index.php'" style="width: 15%; font-size: 30px; font-family: ar essence; position: absolute; top: 20%; height: 60%; left: 60%;" type="button">
</div>
<div style="width: 50%; background-color: rgb(199, 255, 202); position: absolute; left: 25%; top: 20%; height: 30%;" class="jumbotron">
<form action="lien.php" method="POST">
<input placeholder="sujet" name="sujet" style="position: absolute; width: 50%; height: 16%; top: 10%; font-size: 175%; font-family: ar essence; left: 25%;" type="text">
<textarea placeholder="question" name="question" style="position: absolute; width: 50%; height: 45%; top: 29%; font-size: 175%; font-family: ar essence; left: 25%;" type="text"></textarea>
    <input value="Submit" name="submit" style="width: 21%; font-size: 150%; font-family: ar essence; height: 10%; left: 39%; top: 74%; position: absolute;" type="submit">
</form>
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Please, fix your question. You have a bunch of typos... Also, explain your problem a bit more. Do you get any errors? It's hard to read your code when it's all red.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate the strings in your insert query in quotes (").

```
$stmt = $dbh->exec('INSERT INTO `u486645433_membr`.`posta` (`sujet`,    `question`, `id`) VALUES ("'.$username.'", "'.$password.'", NULL);');
//                                                                                                ^             ^  ^             ^
```

Some other notices:

- It would be better to use prepared statements. See "SQL Injection" as one reason
- Default is ERRMODE_SILENT, which hides any error, better use ERRMODE_EXCEPTION or at least ERRMODE_WARNING (kind of legacy).
- If your primary key is default auto-increment you don't need to mention it. Better omit all not necessary columns.
- As long as working with just one database (per PDO connection) don't write its name in the query, set it once when connecting (what you already do)

Example:

```
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
// [...]
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `u486645433_membr`.`posta` ' .
//                   ^ dbname?
    '(`sujet`, `question`) VALUES (?, ?)';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($username, $password));
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste this code:

```
<?php
$hostdb="";
$namedb="";
$userdb="";
$passdb="";


if(isset($_POST['submit'],$_POST['question'],$_POST['sujet'])){

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql ="INSERT INTO `u486645433_membr`.`posta` (`sujet`,    `question`, `id`) VALUES (:user, :pass, :id) 
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindValue(":user", $_POST['sujet']);
            $statement->bindValue(":pass", $_POST['question']);
            $statement->bindValue(":id", null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $count = $statement->execute();

        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
?>
```